# 16 GB USB Flash Drive gives an error when I want to copy files from it to a hard drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have 16GB USB flash drive. when I want to copy files from my flash drive to a hard drive, gives the following message.

[image: Error]

It hasn't any virus.

What can I do?

Here are two screenshots.

[image: Benchmark]

[image: Health]

Comment: Have you used over 2GB or 4GB of its capacity successfully before? Can you write to it (_for example take 1GB file, [md5sum it](http://www.md5summer.org/), write file to flash, md5sum again from flash. It should report exactly same checksum._)? Does it report correctly capacity/free/used space? Filesystem type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible that you have an USB stick that has less actual memory than what it reports to the system. This can happen with too-good-to-be-true offers for these (essentially this would mean fraud).

To verify this, try copying smaller files to the USB. E.g. copy multiple versions of an 500mb file to the stick and see how many fit onto it before it reports errors (if any). If it is fraud, it is not uncommon that it will work fine with 2GB or 4GB, but fail beyond that.

If you think it is a well known brand (e.g. Kingston, etc.) from a good source, try contacting their support. It may as well be just a bad memory chip on board.

Comment: I have one 16GB Kingston MicroSD that is fake, it is really 2GB card. It was inside original  16GB Kingston package (_or very good fraud with nice holograms and everything, just like real ones_). Card also has original Kingston logo and 16GB capacity stamp. However, that does not essentially mean that card is fake if you cant read/write from/to it. +1 for good answer.

Comment: @Sampo my flash drive has real capacity and it isn't fake because I bought that last year and it worked very well. As you can see in Figures it made with Silicon Power Co.

Comment: I agree with @Collaborator. My USB Flash Drive had hardware problem and it became clear when I went to support center and they said to me. I changed that with another Silicon power USB flash. Thank You and +1

Answer (score 1):

you have a fake 16gb key, it is probably a 1gb which pretend to be 16gb.
verify your key with h2testw
find it yourself with google, here for instance:
http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/H2testw.shtml

Comment: the OP _might_ have a fake thumb drive, but one couldn't say that for sure with the information given.

Comment: great ! wanna bet ??